# nextJS 13 API is not giving request URL query data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-api

I am getting data from the Vercel database using Drizzele as ORM in NextJS 13 API routes but the issue is I am getting cookies value user_id from the user that sends a request to my GET function API which is in app/api/cart/route.ts and I will than end that data to user through server function that function will do something like from API response extract product_id value and by putting that value in groq query will filter data and return I will render that data on my page
below is the code for my GET API function
(in this function I am getting error )

```js
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const user_id = request.nextUrl;
  console.log(user_id);
  const uid = user_id.searchParams.get("user_id") as string;
  console.log(uid);
  try {
    const query = await db
      .select()
      .from(table)
      .where(eq(table.user_id, `${uid}`));
    console.log(query);
    return NextResponse.json(query);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "something went wrong" });
  }
}
```

my functions that's sending request to API :

```js
 const datafetch = async () => {
   const user_id = cookies().get("user_id")?.value;
   const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/cart/${user_id}`, {
     method: "GET",
   });
   if (!data.ok) {
     console.log("Failed to fetch data");
   }
   return data.json();
 };
 export default datafetch;
```

so there is something wrong with my API function or the way I am calling this this way

```js
const datafetch = async () => {
  const data = await fetch(`api/cart/`, {
    method: "GET",
  });
  if (!data.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  return data.json();
};
```